# Are meters and gauges in codahale metrics sensitive to the limitations of lossy sampling?

Tags: java, dropwizard, metrics, codahale-metrics

I've recently come across [this article](https://lab.getbase.com/aggregating-response-time/) regarding the limitations of calculating latency percentiles using lossy sampling with and exponentially decaying reservoir such as used in [codahale metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics).

As far as I understand the gauges and meters are based on deltas of AtomicLong values. So the m1 m5 m15 values are therefore counter based and shouldn't miss any events even under high load. Is this definitely the case?